# Python get original list name from class function

Tags: python, variables, global

Thanks for the help.
How can I access the global variable name when I import a class?  I have multiple lists of numbers with variable names

```
apples=[1,2,3]
bananas=[4,5,6]
coconuts=[7,8,9]
```

I want to call from a helper class function that I call from an external file called funk.py in order to put these into a pandas dataFrame()

```
class funk:
def __init__(self,*args):
data=pd.DataFrame()
###if apples is in the list
data['Apples']=apples
###if bananas is in the list
data['Bananas']=bananas
###if bananas is in the list
data['Bananas']=bananas
###if bananas is in the list
data['Bananas']=bananas
###if coconuts is in the list
data['Coconuts']=coconuts
return data
```

and then call `funk.funk(apples,bananas)`

I dont know how to reference the individual inputs, lists by their original name.  I could add the individual list that are possible explicitly in the arguments of the function, but that seems almost redundant.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to do things the way you are asking since it is not explicit, could be hard to debug,  one value can have multiple variable names, and it probably wouldnt work as expected if called inside a function (you should avoid relying on things being globals).

Also you probably mean to use a function instead of a class. You can't return values out of a class constructor like your code shows, and since you don't make any use of a self variable you probably don't have any state to track between method calls and therefore don't actually want a class.

It would be better for you to use a function with keyword arguments. Also did you deliberately mean to capitalize the column names?

```py
import pandas as pd
def funk(**kwargs):
    data=pd.DataFrame()
    for kw,val_list in kwargs.items():
        data[kw.capitalize()] = val_list
    return data
apples=[1,2,3]
bananas=[4,5,6]
df=funk(apples=apples,bananas=bananas, coconuts=[7,8,9])
```

If you really really wanted to do it the way you asked, and the variables really were in the global module space then you could do the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
def funk(*args):
    args_ids = set([id(arg) for arg in args])
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for name,value in globals().items():
        if id(value) in args_ids:
            data[name.capitalize()] = value
    return data
apples=[1,2,3]
bananas=[4,5,6]
df=funk(apples,bananas)
```

If you really meant to say calling context instead of globals, say if you wanted this to work inside a function, then you could do:

```py
import inspect, pandas as pd

def funk(*args):
    args_ids = set([id(arg) for arg in args])
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for name,value in inspect.stack()[1].frame.f_locals.items():
        if id(value) in args_ids:
            data[name.capitalize()] = value
    return data
apples=[1,2,3]
bananas=[4,5,6]
df=funk(apples,bananas)
```

Now one reason the latter two solutions are bad ideas is the following:

```py
apples=[1,2,3]
bananas=[4,5,6]
coconuts = bananas
df=funk(apples,bananas)
```

This dataframe will actually contain three columns: Apples, Bananas, and Coconuts because the coconuts object was in the argument list since the bananas and coconuts variable names both refer to the same object. Accepting only one of them is not a solution because the code won't know which variable name, bananas or coconuts was the one used to call it - you would have a 50/50 guess. This could be worked around by actually inspecting the calling source code and looking for the names passed to the function. This is doable, but we are getting ridiculous. This is not how the language is meant to be used and your code will very likely have bugs. You should just use the keyword arguments approach at the top of this answer, which is an ok way of doing things.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
import filename
class funk:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        data=pd.DataFrame()
        ###if apples is in the list
        data['Apples']= filename.apples
        ###if bananas is in the list
        data['Bananas']= filename.bananas
        ###if coconuts is in the list
        data['Coconuts']= filename.coconuts
        self.data = data
```

Comment: `__init__` should always return `None`.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that just copied from the question.